# Big Red X in windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagrid

[image]I had seen lot of explanation about the possible reasons behind Red X after googling. Our application displaying only certain systems and only at rare times. Can any body suggest me test case to produce Big Red X in any c# controls preferably DataGrid. I checked the test case given in blog http://www.sturmnet.org/blog/2005/03/23/red-x ,but no way to produce. My main intention is to do some R & D about this issue

Comment: Are you using RDP to remote into a computer where the application is running? I've seen this problem occur when remoting into a Windows Server 2008 machine.

Comment: @frinkenstein789 Our application is client server based and the problem is seeing in workstation windows 7 side.Thats okey any body has any test case to reproduce this issue

Comment: I have posted my eception, most of the time while doing RDP, only one time noted in my system when that was workstation(not sure it happened, Will it depend up on environement?)

Comment: Are you trying to reproduce big red X in the linked article? Then you should have posted it instead of the above screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big red X occurs when an unhandled exception is being thrown during a `Paint` event. To reproduce, create the following test class:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
  protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs pevent)
  {
    throw new Exception("my test exception");
  }
}
```

Build and place this component onto your form. When you start the app, you will see the following image:

[image]

You are also likely to see this error for the first time it fails to do `Paint`:

[image]

Comment: can you convert this in to c#?